# PHP Codeigniter wont load CSS-File

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter

Good evening,

I started using Codeigniter as Framework for my newest projekt... and already got problems on the first page.

I want to link a CSS file to my site. It looks perfectly good in the Code. But just nothing happens.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Tec.Net</title>
    <?php 
    $this->load->helper('html');
    echo link_tag($data['css']);
    ?>
</head>
<body>
    <h1><?php echo $title ?></h1>
```

This is the code of my header.php

```
body {
background-image: url("application/views/images/Console Background.png");
color: white;
}
```

The standard.css

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Tec.Net</title>
    <link href="localhost/TecNet/standard.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Home</h1>
    <h2>this is a home site</h2>    <em>&copy; 2015</em>
</body>
</html>
```

And at last. The code i receive from Firefox. The Link is perfectly fine. If i try to access it directly from my browser it opens the css file. As inline CSS the code works perfect just that link refuses to work

**EDIT:**
my URL Structure for the controller.

```
http://localhost/TecNet/index.php/tecnet/view
```

And the controller itself

```
<?php
class Tecnet extends CI_Controller {

 public function view($page = 'home')
 {
    if ( ! file_exists(APPPATH.'/views/pages/'.$page.'.php')) {
            // Whoops, we don't have a page for that!
            show_404();
        }

    $data['title'] = ucfirst($page); // Capitalize the first letter

    $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('pages/'.$page, $data);

    $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Load your helpers in your autoload.php file (in config folder) or in the controller.  not in the view. @ichadhr answer will solve your dilemma.

Answer (score 1):

Try to load your style sheet like this:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?= base_url('TecNet/standard.css') ?>">
```

Comment: didn't work. It gave me the same link. Thanks anyway

Comment: have you removed `'index.php` from your url? If so, have you also added are rewrite rule for *css? Your css files should be in CI project root as well.

Comment: I added a route to the default controller `$route['default_controller'] = 'tecnet/view';` but i didn't add a rewrite rule. The file is in my document root. Alongside with the index.php. Not under /system.

Comment: can you edit your question and add an example of your url structure?

Comment: if your url does not include index.php, then yes, you have vhost/htaccess rewrite rules....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87408/discussion-between-kisaragi-and-chase).

Comment: if you don't have your server configured for short tags / asp style tags try
`<link href="<?php echo base_url("css/bootstrap.css"); ?>" rel="stylesheet">`.  not everyone has their php.ini file setup to use `<?=`

Comment: @b_dubb please read [this carefully](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/alternative_php.html) even PHP ini file disabled "short tags" CodeIgniter will optionally rewrite short tags on-the-fly.

Answer (score 1):

since CodeIgniter is based on the Model-View-Controller development pattern. Better you put resoures of css, img, js, etc.. in `root` folder instead on view like you did:

```
background-image: url("application/views/images/Console Background.png");
```

assume structures:

```
/standard.css
/assets/img/console-background.png
```

your standart.css file:

```
body {
background-image: url("assets/img/console-background.png");
color: white;
}
```

easy to call in view:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?= base_url('standard.css') ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

I use assests a bit  differently in CI, load with controller dynamically, but maybe this can work for you:

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/css/your_style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

just replace path, so they will match to yours